# non-atomic complete Boolean lattice

Tags: examples-counterexamples, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Is there a Boolean complete lattice that is not atomic?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. For an example, take the Boolean algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and mod out by the ideal of measure $0$ sets.

Comment: Please explain what "mod out" means

Comment: You can form the quotient Boolean algebra modulo an ideal, just the way you form the quotient ring modulo an ideal or the quotient group modulo a normal subgroup. Essentially, two elements of the algebra become equal in the quotient just when their symmetric difference lies in the ideal. Google "quotient Boolean algebra" for more details.

Comment: Why is this Boolean algebra complete?

Comment: @CharlesRezk It's easy, but not trivial. Let $B$ be this Boolean algebra. It suffices to show that $B$ has arbitrary joins. So let $A\subseteq B$. We may assume $A$ is closed under finite unions. Let $r = \sup\{\mu(X)\mid [X]\in A\}$ (writing $[X]$ for the equivalence class of $X$). Then we can find a sequence $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of measurable sets such that $[X_n]\in A$ for all $n$ and $\mu(X_n)$ approximates $r$ from below. It follows that $[\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} X_n]$ is the join of $A$.

Comment: I don't see why it must be the join in the case that $\mu(\bigcup X_n)=\infty$.

Comment: Oh, good point. I was thinking of the case of the unit interval. But you can put the reals in continuous bijection with $(0,1)$ in a way that sends measure $0$ sets to measure $0$ sets. So the Lebesgue measure algebra for the reals (measurable sets mod measure $0$ sets) is isomorphic to the Lebesgue measure algebra for the unit interval. @CharlesRezk

Comment: Ok thanks.......